# WriteReg function gives error for large registry values

Tags: registry, nsis

In NSIS i am using WriteRegBin. But if the length of value is large(about more than 15000 characters) then while compiling nsi code it will not work and compiling stops.
For example(Below code has if has about more than 1500 characters then error comes)

```
WriteRegBin HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE "SOFTWARE\nnn\qwrtt\B4CA2970-DD2B-11D0-9DFA-00AA00AF3494020000000000500002000000000000003070693300000000000000000400000000.....etc etc etc..
```

So how it can be solved. I know i can use importing registry file as shown below.

```
ExecWait '"regedit.exe" /s "$TEMP\registryfile.reg"'
```

But how i can i manage in WriteRegBin function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current example has a long **key** name and those are [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724872%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to have a limit of 255 characters.

MSDN also tells you:

> Long values (more than 2,048 bytes) should be stored in a file, and
>   the location of the file should be stored in the registry. This helps
>   the registry perform efficiently.

I don't know the exact NSIS REG_BINARY limit but if you want to bypass it you could call the registry functions directly with the system plugin...